# PyAutoGUI error attempting to use pyautogui.press()

Tags: pyautogui

Trying to get PyAutoGUI to press both z button and x button at the same time on the keyboard causes an error. It assumes the second entry is presses, but it's not.

I have refered to the official documentation and accordingly this should work, yet fails.

---

```
import pyautogui
from time import sleep

x = 0
stop = 10
while x < stop:
    pyautogui.press('z', 'x')
    sleep(0.1)
    x+=1
```

---

From Official Documentation:

To press multiple keys similar to what write() does, pass a list of strings to press(). For example:

> > > pyautogui.press(['left', 'left', 'left'])

Or you can set how many presses left:

> > > pyautogui.press('left', presses=3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, my eyes failed to see the [ ]'s, and now it works.  Answered my own question.

```
import pyautogui
from time import sleep

x = 0
stop = 10
while x < stop:
    pyautogui.press(['z', 'x'])
    sleep(0.1)
    x+=1
```